# In this sentence, do we use “journalisées” or “journaliser”?

Tags: grammaire, passif

Do we say :

> La validation et l'édition doivent être journalisées.

or

> La validation et l'édition doivent être journaliser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une tournure passive : *être + participe passé*. On écrit donc :

> La validation et l'édition doivent être journalisées.

Notes : 
*Journaliser* est un néologisme (mais il en faut bien un), qui ne sera compris que des informaticiens. Il y a aussi de fortes chances que *édition* soit mal utilisé cf [sa définition](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9dition), l'anglais *edit* se traduit souvent par *modification* (qu'il faudrait mettre au pluriel dans cette phrase).

Answer (score 0):

C'est naturellement la première proposition. Il faut employer un participe passé et non un infinitif.

It's, of course, the former. One have to use « participe passé » and not « infinitif ».